# Find 2 x values of the current y in a List(of Point)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have a `List(of PointF)`.
2 nested for loops run through a rectangle that is stretched around a circle (or circle-ish (but is really is a closed path)). I want to work within this circle with `GetPixel(x,y)`. That means, I need the respective minimum and maximum x value of the respective y. How can I work that out with this List(Of PointF)?
The reason I'm requesting help here is because I get confused with these `List.Find(predicates or matches)`things[image].

```
For x As Integer = CInt(xmin) To CInt(xmax) Step 1
            For y As Integer = CInt(ymin) To CInt(ymax) Step 1
                'get the min and max value of x here
            Next      
Next
```

**Edit:** It's about: I wrote a program that uses gray images and Laplace to perform edge detection. A rectangle was drawn with the mouse and a search was made for edges within it. A `Drawing2D.GraphicsPath` was then created. This worked more or less well according to the object shown in the photo, because the rectangle had to be enlarged accordingly.
Now my idea is that I draw a freehand GraphicsPath myself (instead of a rectangle) and let it search for edges within it. That's why I have this circle (or egg) and I have to make sure that I don't get over its borders. I could already work out xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax, but not x1 and x2 (see drawing).
So as I loop through all of the points from xmin to xmax and ymin to ymax, I want to know if the current point is inside the shape.
*I have to check whether its x value is between the shape's x range for the given y and then the reverse for the y value. That's my problem. How to use the List?*

Comment: I like the question, but I'm not following you exactly. Are you wanting to know if a specified point is within the closed shape (*not necessarily* a circle)? Are `xmin/xmax` and `ymin/ymax` specified or are they to be determined? Probably a bit more info would assist. PS You don't need the `Step 1`s; +1 is the default.

Comment: Hi @SteveCinq xmin / xmax and ymin / ymax are available. These are the Dimensions of the rectangle.

"Are you wanting to know if a specified point is within the closed shape?" Yes, exactly. Thus, I always have to look at the current y to see what x1 and x2 are.

Comment: And how is the shape defined? As a set of points or by some kind of function?

Comment: Oh, actually this is a `Drawing2D.GraphicsPath` that was drawn by hand. I thought I'd put its points in a List(of point) because it's more advantageous. Isn't it?

Comment: A list of points is probably easier to examine in relation to the location of any specified point. So `xmin/xmax` and `ymin/ymax` are really just defining the vertical and horizontal extent of the shape, nothing more, correct?

Comment: "...are really just defining the vertical and horizontal extent of the shape, nothing more, correct?" Correct :)

Comment: You should describe (better) what you actually want to achieve and what issues you have instead of asking help in relation to the method you think you should use to solve the problem. First thing, you don't use `GetPixel()` to to parse the Colors of an Image, you use [Image.LockBits()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits), then, [GraphicsPath.IsOutlineVisible()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.isoutlinevisible) can tell you whether a Point along an axis is contained in the outline (is on the Path border).

Comment: What does *I want to work within this circle* mean, in practice? What is the end goal? (Add the information to the question).

Comment: @Jimi I've done it

Comment: As mentioned, `GraphicsPath.IsOutlineVisible()` tells you whether the current position in on the Path border, while [GraphicsPath.IsVisible()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.isvisible) tells whether a Point is contained in the GraphicsPath bounds.

Comment: " GraphicsPath.IsVisible() " Thanks, that's waht I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're better off not `For`-looping through the entire space. That would work but it's more effort than I think you need computationally.

Given a point, to determine whether or not it is within your shape - as defined by a list of point - you should only need to compare the defined point's x and y co-ords with the shape list.

Eg, Given a point x=100px and y=100px, you know that you have to check whether its x value is between the shape's x range for a the given y (100px) (or the reverse for the y value).

This would (probably?) only work for a simple shape that does not "turn in on itself" or has a curvature that doesn't change polarity. (Not sure what the mathematical name for that is, but there is one.) An hour-glass shape, for example, would probably present greater difficulty.

**UPDATE**

Here's a simple Linq approach which determines whether a specified point is within a defined shape. Note that it excludes points *on* the extremity of the shape but you can include these by changing ">" to ">=", etc.

For simplicity, I've used an octagon to approximate a circle. Also, the code assumes that ALL points within the bitmap are defined for the shape. That is, no interpolation is used.

```
    Dim s As List(Of Point) = New List(Of Point) From {New Point(50, 0), New Point(25, 25), New Point(0, 50), New Point(25, 75), New Point(50, 100), New Point(75, 75), New Point(100, 50), New Point(75, 25)}
    Dim p As Point = New Point(30, 75) ' Is inside the shape
    Dim IsInside As Boolean = s.Exists(Function(f) f.Y = p.Y AndAlso f.X < p.X) AndAlso s.Exists(Function(f) f.Y = p.Y AndAlso f.X > p.X)
```

There're probably ways to combine the Linq test, but you get the idea.

Comment: "This would (probably?) only work for a simple shape that does not "turn in on itself" or has a curvature that doesn't change polarity." That's right, good point, but the shape doesn't get any more complicated than this circle-like shape :)

"you have to check whether its x value is between the shape's x range for a the given y (100px) and then the reverse for the y value." And this is where i struggle

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, there are 2 answers:
The solution by @SteveCinq and the solution by @Jimi.

```
Dim IsInside As Boolean = s.Exists(Function(f) f.Y = p.Y AndAlso f.X < p.X) AndAlso s.Exists(Function(f) f.Y = p.Y AndAlso f.X > p.X)
```

```
GraphicsPath.IsVisible()
```