# Accelerate program: How do I find xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax from a Drawing2D.GraphicsPath?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I'm drawing a `Drawing2D.GraphicsPath` freehand („selbstgezeichneterPath“). This is definitely a simple, closed figure. From this, I only want to determine the vertical and horizontal extent of the shape.
In [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65863671/find-2-x-values-of-the-current-y-in-a-listof-point), which was concerned with determining whether a point lies within the shape, I said that I know xmin, ..., but now I think my procedure is too slow. Is there a way to work out the 4 points faster?

[image: find xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax to be able to draw a rectangle around the shape]

```
Dim xmin As Single = 2000
        Dim xmax As Single = 0
        Dim ymin As Single = 2000
        Dim ymax As Single = 0

        For i As Integer = 0 To selbstgezeichneterPath.PointCount - 1 Step 1
            If selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints(i).X < xmin Then
                xmin = selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints(i).X
            End If
            If selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints(i).Y < ymin Then
                ymin = selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints(i).Y
            End If
            If selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints(i).X > xmax Then
                xmax = selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints(i).X
            End If
            If selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints(i).Y > ymax Then
                ymax = selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints(i).Y
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
Dim xmin As Single = selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints.Min(Function(p) p.X)
Dim xmax As Single = selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints.Max(Function(p) p.X)
Dim ymin As Single = selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints.Min(Function(p) p.Y)
Dim ymax As Single = selbstgezeichneterPath.PathPoints.Max(Function(p) p.Y)
```